# Python Calling windows api VkKeyScan returns random value

Tags: python, windows, api, debugging, dll

I wrote a tiny dll in C++ ,which called the windows api **VkKeyScan**.
But every time I call it ,it returns a random value to me .

```
#include "Windows.h"
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) auto func()//return random values, unless change auto to int
{
    return VkKeyScan('a');
};
```

If I simply change the return type of the function from **auto** to **int** ,it always returns the right value (which is 65).

Or if I use VkKeyScanA('a') instead of VkKeyScan('a'), it also returns the right value all the time .(both VkKeyScanA and VkKeyScan return short integers)

I wonder what causes this bug ?

Calling VkKeyScanW using ctypes returns random values too.

```
from ctypes import *

print(windll.user32.VkKeyScanW(c_wchar('a')))//return random values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VkKeyScan` actually returns a `SHORT` (16-bit int type) and the remaining upper bits in the return register are undefined.

I'm guessing that auto keeps the type as a short and the code that calls `func` is the problem, it treats it as a 32-bit value even though there is only 16-bits of defined data there. Forcing the return type to `int` will sign extend from 16 to 32 bits.

ctypes probably has the same issue and is either not declared as returning a `c_int16` or not properly sign-extending when used as a parameter for `print`.

Comment: I don't think so, if I write auto func(){return short(65);}, calling func in python it will always return 65,

Comment: Undefined also means that the upper bits could be zero. `return short(65)` might be compiled as `mov eax, 65; ret;` and that would make all 32-bits valid.

Comment: Thank you ,that explains a lot .